# Ansible facter - CentOS - not showing any facter_ variables

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, ansible-2.x, facter

I have two boxes:
- CentOS 7.2.x.x vagrant box
and
- Debian/Ubuntu 14.04 trusty vagrant box

On both, I installed Ansible (using their preferred package manager method) and ansible/ansible-playbook commands are working perfectly on both boxes.

On CentOS box, installed Ansible version is:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.1.2.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```

On Ubuntu box, installed Ansible version is:

```
ansible 2.2.0.0
```

On both Ubuntu and CentOS vagrant boxes, When I'm running the following command, it works! i.e. it's spitting out a lot of JSON formatted output hash/values., great:

```
[vagrant@ip-10-11-12-13 ~/aks/workspace] $ ansible all -m setup -i "`hostname`," --connection=local
```

Now, as I'm specifically looking for **'facter_**someVar' variables (which can give me some meaningful information about the local box), so I tried to **grep** --> **"facter_"** word from the output of the previous command.

```
[vagrant@ip-10-11-12-13 ~/aks/workspace] $ ansible all -m setup -i "`hostname`," --connection=local | grep "facter_"
[vagrant@ip-10-11-12-13 ~/aks/workspace] $
```

I found that on Ubuntu box, it's showing me a lot of **facter_xxxx** matching variables (around 71+), but on CentOS box, I'm **NOT** getting  **ANY** *facter_* variable in the output?

I recall, in past, I have used CentOS boxes (vagrant provisioned) and they all showed facter_ variables.

I know there are similar **'ansible_**someVar' variables but I'm curious about why **facter_xxxxx** variables are not showing up here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I was missing *facter* package on my other box. The following solved the issue (you may need to get the respective EPEL repo).

```
sudo yum install facter
```

**Facter** is small program that gathers system information such as hardware details, network settings, virtualisation type and kernel/OS information. Seems like Facter was created for **Puppet** to gather system information (but is also available as a standalone command) so it was not installed for free on the particular vagrant CentOS image I used.